# failed connect to lvmetad. falling back to device scanning

Tags: linux, kali-linux, lvm

I started upgrading linux times. then stop there that fail then I repeat and the result is same.

when i reboot then the only view is initramfs. I try to use fsck tools, but there is even so as in the following picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGVbI.jpg)